# How to generate email when user login in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata

I am developing a project, in that I need to send email to the user who logins

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,BranchID,CreatedDate,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Gender,EmailID,MobileNo")] Master master)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Masters.Add(master);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            User u = new Models.User();

            u.UserID = master.FirstName.Length > 4 ? agentMaster.FirstName.Substring(0, 4) : agentMaster.FirstName;
            u.Password = u.UserID + "@123";
            u.EmailID = agentMaster.EmailID;
            u.Mobile = agentMaster.MobileNo;
            u.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            u.Name = agentMaster.FirstName;
            u.Createdby = agentMaster.FirstName;
            u.EmailConfirmed = true;
            u.PhoneNumberConfirmed = true;
            u.ID = agentMaster.ID;

            db.Users.Add(u);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            sendMail(u.EmailID, master.FirstName, u.UserID, u.Password);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
     return View(master);
    }



    public void sendMail(string EmailID, string FirstName, string UserID, string Password)
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(EmailID);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString());
        mail.Subject = "User Registration";

        string Body = PopulateBody(FirstName, UserID, Password);
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpHost"].ToString();
        smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"].ToString());
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserPwd"].ToString());// Enter seders User name and password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);

    }

   private string PopulateBody(string FirstName, string UserID, string Password)
    {
        string body = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Utilities/EmailTemplate.htm")))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        body = body.Replace("{UserName}", FirstName);
        body = body.Replace("{UserID}", UserID);
        body = body.Replace("{Password}", Password);
        return body;
    }
```

This is my controller part to send email

I have two table called `Mater` and `User`, the value which is given through create method are saved in the database. But in the sendmail method, I'am getting an error:

> object reference is not set to an instance of an object" in the following line.
>
> mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString());

`MailMessage` and `MailAddress` are taken from the metadata. but it showing an error like this?

can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: its clear from the message that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"]` is getting null

Comment: how ? what can i do to change ?

Comment: i thing there is a problem in appsettings maybe name is not correct

Comment: can you share appsettings and hide any sensitive data

Comment: i have change the appsetings a solved that problem, but it generates another error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. " in the line smtp.Send(mail); in sendmail method?

Comment: have changed Access for less secure apps turn on and also showing the same error. why is that ?

Comment: its problem with google authentication not code there are many answers in google on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about that

```
<add key="Form" value="yourvalue"/>
```

this setting has in your config file.

Comment: its a 'From' not 'Form'

Comment: ok "Form" or "Form" or "xx", I mean you sure your config has it

Comment: it is From only but shows another error The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. "

Comment: thats another question topic please search on internet, if you can not find solution then create a new question.